# Why WebView in JavaFX has many imperfections?

Tags: webview, javafx

i'm working to build a `web browser` everything works fine i don't have any mistake while running the program but the webview while running has those imprefections:

```
    •can't resize (zoom) the web page with `Ctrl+plus button` 
    •can't download in photo by clicking the rightside of the mouse and choosing        "save the photo" 
•can't read the videos espacially the Youtube 
•old design in google search
```

and much more...
so this is my code that open a web page in webview by clicking on a button:

```
 but1.setOnAction(new EventHandler <ActionEvent> (){

         public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
             String stri = text11.getText();
            WebEngine myWebEngine = web1.getEngine();

            myWebEngine.load("https://www.google.com");
         }

     });
```

so please can any body tell me what's wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

you can't expect everything to go the way you want with just a few lines of code...

to fix the old google you need to change the user agent in your engine

```
myWebEngine.setUserAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.44 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/8.0 JavaFX/8.0 Safari/537.44");
```

should fix that problem you're having

if you want a "save" to popup on images you will have to implement you're old context menu on the webview

Comment: sorry but this method dosen't exist :(

Comment: you must be using an older version, just did a quick google & that method may of only been added to jfx-8 also maybe that's when zooming in and out of pages got added I just can't remember how I did it before so I can't show you